# Building a robot simulator GUI using C#. Need some advice

Tags: c#, winforms, simulator

I'm building a 2D robot simulator GUI for my autonomous robot vehicle.

I plan to keep the GUI simple. It consists of a vehicle (represented by a blue square picture), and some obstacles (cones, wall, etc, represented by yellow circle and red line respectively).

The vehicle must be able to move (as in the blue square must be able to move on the GUI) and be able to show its velocity and steering (float values) and its status (string) on the GUI.

I plan to use C# and Windows Forms to do this task, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to it. I remember using picture box a few years ago and I was not able to change the position of the picture box in real-time, or something weird like that.

Just wondering if you guys know a better way to do this. Is Windows Forms the way to go?

I've just moved from Ubuntu to Windows, so I am quite new at .Net stuff.

Here's what I've got so far http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/guilo.png/

Comment: The UX guidelines say that is not what the ribbon is for

Comment: What would you suggest instead of the ribbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future plans may dictate a change, but for what you describe Windows.Drawing should work fine.  The only problem may be if you are using timers for updates, as it may not be fast enough for you.

So, how fast of an update rate do you need?

How much like a game framework will you actually need?

You may want to look at a tutorial like:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67275-the-wonders-of-systemdrawinggraphics/

Comment: The update loop needs at most 10 frames per second. Not sure what you mean by game framework, but I do need the picture box to update its position every frame.

Comment: At 10 FPS, you can simply go on with what you want to do; it should be more than enough.

Comment: @pandascope - By a game framework, in this simulator, will you be using a more complicated mechanism for determining where shapes are drawn, or to allow people to interact with the simulator, but if you just want to show where your robot is that will work fine.